# Javascript call and apply functions only called on first argument?

Tags: javascript, call, apply

*Edit: this question was asked due to my misunderstanding. Proceed with caution, as reading it might waste your time.*

I thought `call` and `apply` would execute a function given a set of arguments, but I'm getting confusing test results. See my test code:

```
window.z = 0;
(function(){++(window.z)}).call(this, 1, 2, 3)
```

I would expect `z` to be 3 after execution. However, z is 1.

```
(function(){++(window.z)}).apply(this, [1, 2, 3])
```

Same here. `z == 1;`
I tried simply logging the input argument as well:

```
var x = function(y){console.log(y);}
x.call(this, 1, 2, 3);
```

Result? Only 1 is logged.
What am I doing wrong here?

(Tested in Chrome and Firefox with Firebug.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) only call the function once. The difference is how the arguments to the invocation are passed.

With call, each parameter after the context (first parameter), is a parameter. With apply, the second parameter should be an array *like* object of parameters (the first parameter still provides the context).

```
function foo(a, b, c) {

};

foo.call(this, 1, 2, 3); // a == 1, b == 2, c == 3;
foo.apply(this, [1,2,3]); // a == 1, b == 2, c == 3;
```

If you want to call the function multiple times, you can accomplish this by simply putting the call in a loop.

Answer (score 3):

This is expected, the arguments you pass will be present in your increment function (as `arguments` see [here for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)), but you are only calling the function once.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are under the impression that the `call` and `apply` methods should call the functon once for each parameter. That is not the case, it only calls the function once.

The `apply` methods takes an array of arguments:

```
func.apply(this, [1, 2, 3]);
```

The `call` methods takes an argument list:

```
func.call(this, 1, 2, 3);
```